# Regex pattern matching not working in scala.js?

Tags: regex, scala, scala.js

Here is the code:

```
val s =
  """
    |\begin{bmatrix}
    |\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
    |\sin \theta & \cos \alpha
    |\end{bmatrix}
  """.stripMargin

val lastWordPattern = """(?s)(.*)\s+(.*)""".r
def wordToPos(string: String, position: Int): String = {
  val subString = string.substring(0, position)
  println("sub: ", subString)
  subString match {
    case lastWordPattern(x@_*) => {
      println(0, x(0))
      println(1, x(1))
      x(0)
    }
    case _ => ""
  }
}
wordToPos(s, 20)
```

Result from `sbt console`:

```
scala>     wordToPos(s, 20)
(sub: ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\co)
(0,
\begin{bmatrix})
(1,\co)
```

Result from chrome:

```
(sub: ,
\begin{bmatrix}
\co)
```

In chrome the code prints the substring, but fails to match the regex.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it is because JS does not support `(?s)` modifier. Try replacing all `.` with `[\s\S]` and retry.

Comment: Indeed, that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JavaScript does not support singleline modifier (neither inline, nor a regular one), you need to replace every `.` outside the character class with `[\s\S]` (a character class with opposite shorthand classes that matches *any* symbol there can be in a string).

With `[\s\S]`, you will match any symbol including a newline without the need to specify the singleline mode.

```
val lastWordPattern = """([\s\S]*)\s+([\s\S]*)""".r
```